# Is a lambda without capture list usually implemented as ordinary function?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

This question origins from another question that [Why isn't a lambda that captures variables by reference convertible to a function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692007/why-isnt-a-lambda-that-captures-variables-by-reference-convertible-to-a-functio)
 . It seems like that the lambda with a capture list is implemented as a local class with `operator ()`.

As far as I know, lambda without capture list could be converted to a function pointer, which seems like it's just a ordinary function. What's more, I could not find anything special when compared the lambda without capture list with ordinary function.

At the same time, I think there is no necessity to not implement lambda without capture list as ordinary function.

Comment: " I think there is no necessity to not implement lambda without capture list as ordinary function." I use lambda very often and it feels comfortable to *can* do this. Writing a stand alone function and take the address is simply more work todo. And it splits function definition and usage which *can* be avoided by using capture less lambda. So simply I have the necessity to use it ;)

Comment: Please do `not` use `random` code `markups`.

Comment: @T.C. OK, I've re-edited the post.

Comment: Do mean by the compiler or as a programmer?

Comment: The capture-less lambda could still be a class object, but with a conversion operator returning a function pointer. It doesn't *have* to be a function itself.

Comment: @BoPersson Where does that function pointer comes from? Is it converted form member function?

Comment: @BoPersson Lambdas _mustn't_ be a function. It must have unique type

Comment: Check the interwebs: [Demystifying C++ lambdas](https://blog.feabhas.com/2014/03/demystifying-c-lambdas/).

Comment: `I think there is no necessity to not implement lambda without` triple negative! A new record!

Comment: @JHBonarius Wow, that's good.

Comment: @PasserBy - It must have a unique type only if someone is checking. If all we do is convert lambdas to function pointers, how do we know if they have different types? Anyway, my point was supposed to be that you can be *convertible* to a function pointer without *being* a function.

Comment: Am I right, that you are interested in an answer specifically for C++ and perhaps the implementation details of a specific compiler, or do you want a more general answer?

Comment: @MichaelBeer This question is asking about implementation details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's more, I could not find anything special when compared the lambda without capture list with ordinary function.

Try to take the `sizeof` of a function and then from a non-capturing lambda. You will notice that the function doesn't have a size (and so it fails to compile), while the lambda does (it's almost always 1)!

So the compiler cannot generate a plain function for the non-capturing lambda. Note that it can and implement an exception for lambda functions under the as-if rule, but I wouldn't call this an ordinary function.

By making the call operator static or working around it (compilers can do a lot of stuff that we cant), the conversion to a function pointer can work.

Comment: Thanks, so it's the compiler that do a lot of stuff behind the scene.

Comment: `sizeof` function is illegal

Comment: @bigxiao Yeah, the compiler can basically do whatever it wants as long as it does the same thing that the standard says.

Comment: @PasserBy hmm, yes that's my point. Is my answer that unclear? I would appreciate it if you could suggest a better way to word it maybe

Comment: I think a compiler (as an extension) may allow it. As for `sizeof([]{})`, it's not guaranteed to be 1 either. That too can vary between compilers.

Comment: @MSalters Thanks, didn't know this! :)

Answer (score 1):

Advantage of structure functor over regular function is that you keep type, which might help in inlining:

```
std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v), &function);
```

would have to remember the value of &function as `bool (*)(const T&, const T&)` to allow inlining.

Whereas, for:

```
std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v),
          [](const T& lhs, const T& rhs){ return function(lhs, rhs);});
```

we have the value anytime we have the `comparer`. No additional work to remember initial value